# tintcolor of alert will change after klick

Tags: swift2, ios9

i use ios 9 swift 2 and i would like to change the button tint color of an alert. this is the code which works fine:

```
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: „Title here", message: „Text here.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let rateAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Button 1", style: .Default) { (action) in
            print(„OK“)
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Button 2", style: .Default) { (action) in
            print(„Cancel")
        }

        alertController.addAction(rateAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {}
        alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor(red: (122/255.0), green: (165/255.0), blue: (23/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

[image]

but if i hold my finger on one button, you can see, that the tintcolor change to default:

[image]

Any Ideas how i can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
your_btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.brownColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

Also, you can set UIColor with RGBA:

```
UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
```